# Concurrent Collection vs locking list

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections, concurrency

Im trying to learn how to work with threads and Im stuck with Concurrent Collections.

I have application, in which I have list `unfinishedOBjectsList<MyObject>` of objects and a method, that do some changes on specific object (something like DoChange(MyObject object) ). After that, that object is taken from first list and inserted in `finishedObjectsList<MyObject>`.

Now, I wanted to run the method using threads, which was working fine - each thread did some changes (changes are minor, so I added ThreadSleep() to simulate some longer processing of object) on specific object it found in unfinishedOBjectsList, removed it from unfinishedOBjectsList and put it in second list.

Next step I wanted to implement was that there would be another method (handled by user using button for example), which would allow user to pick any object from the first list and remove it manualy. The "problem" I wanted to simulate was, that if the object is being "processed" by thread, user should not be able to remove it from list.

I tried ConcurrentQueue - but the problem is, that using Queue, I can not remove specific object (using something like Remove(MyObject) as I can do with list). After that, I tried ConcurrentBag and BlockingCollection, but the problem was the same - I was able to remove the next object in collection, but not for example object in the middle of the collection.

I have thought about using Dictionary, but I cant see reason why I should use dictionary with Key,Value parameters, while I only need to store the object.

My question is - should I even use ConcurrentCollections for this case? Or should I simply lock the list and leave it as it is? What is the right approach when dealing with multiple-access lists?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queues, Stacks, and Bags have the benefit that you don't need to know which object you're getting until you get it. In your case you do know which object you want to manipulate.

It sounds like you have a sort of hybrid model, where you have a processing regime that grabs 'unfinished' objects from a collection, 'finishes' them, then puts them into a 'finished' collection. (It seems you're using lists.)  You also have a user interface that allows a user to choose any given object from the 'unfinished' collection and take it out of that collection.

The way your processing regime *should* work is this:  The code processing objects should

- Remove an object to be processed from the 'unfinished' collection.
- Process the object.
- Place it into the 'finished' collection.
- Repeat.

That is, an object that's currently being processed should never appear in the 'unfinished' collection, because it's removed prior to processing.

Now, if you want to display the items in your 'unfinished' collection to your user, you'll need to iterate through them. You'll also need to give them some sort of key, so when the user clicks on one of them you'll be able to tell which one.

A good way to do this is a serial number, which you increment using `Interlocked.Increment(ref staticSerialNumber)`.

Then you can use a `ConcurrentDictionary<int><yourObject>` collection for your 'unfinished' collection.

To insert a new object into it is easy:

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref staticSerialNumber);
dict.GetOrAdd(staticSerialNumber, newObject);
```

To get a list of objects in it is easy. Use the `dict.GetEnumerator()` method.

To take an item from the dictionary, you can use the enumerator to find the first item, then use `TryRemove(key)` to do that.

In short, a ConcurrentDictionary is probably a good choice for your application.

Comment: That is very well explained, I did not know that there is something like "Interlocked. " before. I will definitely use it and implement it the way you suggested. Thank you for your time and help, I really appreciate it.